# How do I set the WWW-Authentication header in an IAuthenticationFilter implementation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, basic-authentication

I'm implementing basic authentication using MVC5's IAuthenticationFilter interface. My understanding is that this is now the preferred approach instead of using a DelegatingHandler. I've got it working but the www-authenticate header is not being returned in the response. This is my implementation of ChallengeAsync:

```
public async Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await context.Result.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
        if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            result.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "realm=localhost"));
        }
    }
```

The header is returned if I set it in AuthenticateAsync but I think I'm supposed to set it in ChallengeAsync. Sample implementations have been hard to find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `ChallengeAsync`, set `context.Result` to an instance of type `IHttpActionResult`, like so.

```
public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context,
                                  CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    context.Result = new ResultWithChallenge(context.Result);
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Provide an implementation, like so.

```
public class ResultWithChallenge : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly IHttpActionResult next;

    public ResultWithChallenge(IHttpActionResult next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(
                                CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await next.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            response.Headers.WwwAuthenticate.Add(
                   new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "realm=localhost"));
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems like they could have made implementing this easier but this solution works well.

Comment: If you'd like it to be easier, feel free to vote for this work item: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1456

Comment: @JamieIde: Please see this answer from David - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21742491.