# Changing the WWW-Authenticate header when using Azure App Service Authentication

Tags: asp.net, web-services, azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service

This question is related to:

- [Setting Result in the context of ChallengeAsync method in an authentication filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733001/setting-result-in-the-context-of-challengeasync-method-in-an-authentication-filt/21742491)
- [Call a Web API Without Knowing in Advance Its Resource URI or What Authority It Trusts](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/11/04/call-a-web-api-without-knowing-in-advance-its-resource-uri-or-what-authority-it-trusts/)

Trying to get PowerBI to connect to a web API hosted in an Azure App Service using App Service Authentication and the AAD provider.

The WWW-Authenticate header does not identify the identity provider, so [PowerBI does not authenticate to the web API](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Web-Content-Access-Method-WWW-Authenticate-header-doesn-t/td-p/156577).

Can the WWW-Authenticate header be modified, possibly with an [IAuthenticationFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters) when using App Service Authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the WWW-Authenticate header be modified, possibly with an IAuthenticationFilter when using App Service Authentication?

Based on my experience, if we use the WebApp intergrated AAD Authentication, we can't do it with IAuthenticationFilter.

If we [set up the app to use the OWIN authentication pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet#step-2-set-up-the-app-to-use-the-owin-authentication-pipeline), we could do that in respond from ChallengeAsync, you could refer to this [blog](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/webapi-pipeline-revealed-a-true-practical-approach/) to get more detail info.

Comment: This is an old topic, but is this possible to do with an Azure Function with Microsfot IDP enabled? I need to customize the WWW-Authenticate header to include the authorization_uri value